# Side link disappeared after comment removed

Tags: bug

After deleting a comment on [is write() with O_DIRECT ACID compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694870/is-write-with-o-direct-acid-compliant) the side link to [Are disk sector writes atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009063/are-disk-sector-writes-atomic?noredirect=1&lq=1) disappeared from the Linked scction but the comment that was deleted didn't actually contain a link to that page (see [is write() with O_DIRECT ACID compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694870/is-write-with-o-direct-acid-compliant?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment12373656_9694870) which is still linking to it). A link to that question is still in the related section but it was in that section before the comment removal anyway...

Comment: The link is in the "Related" section.  Perhaps they are de-duping them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but wouldn't it be better to de-dupe the other way?